# Rails custom routes with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes, jruby

I am trying to display params in my url so i have added

```
patient_record_path(:limit => 10)
```

I am now trying to correctly route this.
Currently i am getting the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"patient_record", :limit=>10}
```

I am currently using the route

```
match 'patient_record/show&limit', :to => 'patient_record#show'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not add the limit to your route. Just simple define your route like this:

```
match 'patient_record/show', :to => 'patient_record#show', :as => 'patient_record_show'
```

A better solution however would be

```
resources :patient_records
```

This would create the following path helpers:

```
patient_records_path => "/patient_records" => 'patient_record#index'
new_patient_record_path => "/patient_records/new" => 'patient_record#new'
edit_patient_record_path(:id) => /patient_records/:id/edit => 'patient_record#edit'
patient_record_path(:id) => "/patient_records/:id" => 'patient_record#show'
```

### Update: wrong use of path helper

I have looked at your question again and found another bug: the path helper for show needs a record. The correct use is:

```
# path to show
patient_record_path(@patient_record, :limit => 10)

# path to index
patient_records_path(:limit => 10)
```

Comment: Sorry, posted the answer before i was done. Have updated it now :)

Comment: I originally had resources :patient_records and that doesnt work either

Comment: You have a `PatientRecordsController` (in plural, with s in PatientRecord**s**), with the action `show` right?

Comment: yes, all of my other routes work accordingly.  it was when i added patient_record_path(:limit => 10) at the end of my create method that this broke